# Trying to run a Python program but all that opens is a DOS Window

Tags: python, wxpython

I just completed a program that should (hopefully) play a GUI [Tetris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetris) program. I've cleaned up all the syntax errors, but now when I double-click, or go through the Command Prompt to run the program a DOS window pops up for less than a second and disappears without ever running the program.

What's going on?

---

Heres a link to the code at codepad.org

http://codepad.org/tq4et1rO

Comment: go back to your command prompt, type 'python programname.py' and copy the output here.

Comment: Nothing is outputted, before it did but that was because of a Syntax Error which I Fixed

Comment: post the code - too little info

Comment: All 360 lines of the code? :/

Comment: there are websites to post code (seen in other posts).  stick it there, edit your post to point there.

Comment: Could you point me towards a post that talks about one of those websites?

Comment: http://codepad.org is a good choice.

Comment: This would appear to absolutely be a real question - he had a problem, asked about it, was pointed to some steps to make asking and answering better, performed those steps and was informed what was wrong (it was a lot, but that's not the point).  What makes it not a real question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wow, there's really a **huge** number of errors in your code. I started running it under `pdb`, identifying and fixing them one by one, but after 20 or so I gave up.  What I fixed so far (in `diff`'s output, lines start with `<` to mean they're in your version, or with `>` to mean they're in my partially fixed version).  Note the variety: you often write Flase instead of False, use wrong capitalization, use `-` (minus) instead of `=` (equals), misspell variables (e.g. `Boardd` instead of `Board`, `even` instead of `event`), `rnage` instead of `range`, and so on, and so forth.

```
37c37
<       self.isStarted = Flase
---
>       self.isStarted = False
63c63
<       self.isWaitingAfterLine - Flase
---
>       self.isWaitingAfterLine = False
87c87
<       for i in range(Board.BoardHeight * Board.Boardwidth):
---
>       for i in range(Board.BoardHeight * Board.BoardWidth):
135c135
<       if even.GetId() == Boardd.ID_TIMER:
---
>       if event.GetId() == Board.ID_TIMER:
205c205
<       self.curY = Board.Height - 1 + self.curPiece.minY()
---
>       self.curY = Board.BoardHeight - 1 + self.curPiece.minY()
214c214
<       for i in rnage(4):
---
>       for i in range(4):
217c217
<           if x < 0 or x >= Board.BoardWidth or y < 0 or y >= Board.Boardheight:
---
>           if x < 0 or x >= Board.BoardWidth or y < 0 or y >= Board.BoardHeight:
278c278
<       self.coords = [[0, 0] for i in rnage(4)]
---
>       self.coords = [[0, 0] for i in range(4)]
356c356,357
< Tetris(None, -1, 'Tetris')
---
> tetris = Tetris(None, -1, 'Tetris')
> app.SetTopWindow(tetris)
```

After all these fixes, I've stopped upon spotting one more typo (you `def sqaureHeight` when you clearly mean `squareHeight`) -- I have no idea how many typos and other mistakes are still hiding in these 360 lines of code... A density of more such bugs than 1/10th of the lines is plenty high enough for me.

I **heartily** recommend that you start with **much** less ambitious projects and teach yourself to carefully "copyedit" your code for these typos you appear to be so prone to: it's *possible* to be dyslexic **and** an excellent programmer at the same time, but it does take extra effort and diligence on your part.  Tools such as [`pylint`](http://www.logilab.org/857) may also help a little, although they do have limits.

**Edit**: as it turns out, after fixing a couple of occurences of `sqaure` into `square`, the program does run -- and immediately shows an empty window saying "Game Over" and gets to the `raw_input` prompt you have as your very last line.  So beyond the many typos there must be one or more nasty logic-level bugs as well.  I repeat the entreaty to start with something much, **much** simpler in your first forays into programming.

Comment: Great answer, you're so helpful here, Alex. :)

Comment: Yea, I guess I really jumped the gun when doing this. But thanks for your help anyways.

Answer (score 8):

Running your script actually does produce a traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tetris.py", line 356, in <module>
    Tetris(None, -1, 'Tetris')
  File "tetris.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.statusbar - self.CreateStatusBar()
AttributeError: 'Tetris' object has no attribute 'statusbar'
```

Your script has an error on line 10:

```
self.statusbar - self.CreateStatusBar()
```

You mean to be assigning there, not subtracting from an attribute that does not yet exist.

Comment: ah thanks... I don't know what I did because for some reason it doesn't show that on my computer. 

Thanks for the help... I'll go through everything closely and make sure there isn't anything else like that.

Comment: @Brad, see my answer, I identified a couple dozen more "things like that" and fixed them all before posting (my friend and colleague Thomas obviously had the right idea by posting the first bug found instead of taking as long as I did to find them all, given the difference in resulting upvotes;-).

Comment: It's not like you need the votes, Alex :)

Comment: conceded, you're right -- it's just that I always wonder whether I should be thorough or fast in my SO answers, and keeping being biased to thoroughness and thinking maybe I should recalibrate -- back when I responded on comp.lang.python, I always focused on thoroughness (it was never a race based on speed -- Usenet, remember?-), but SO is different (speed _does_ matter here, clearly), so, assuming people's votes do indeed reflect how useful an answer is to them, fast answers appear to be **very** useful to people here, often more than more thorough ones. Hmmm...

Answer (score 2):

An error occurred. Unfortunately, the DOS window closed (because the Python program ended) and you didn't get to see the actual error. Start a DOS window yourself (start -> run -> 'cmd') and run the program from there. That will show you the traceback.

Comment: That's what I did after it wouldn't run from just double clicking it. So I ran it from there and it showed Syntax Errors, I fixed those and it still isn't running. But this time there is no traceback

Comment: You'll have to either show us some code (or post a new question with the code) or do some debugging yourself. Are you sure your script is actually trying to do something? Try adding some print statements to find out what's actually happening.

Comment: So you're saying the reason for this is that there is most likely an error?

Comment: 100% chance there is an error.  Don't be obtuse, take the advice above.

Comment: I didn't mean to sound that way, I'm fairly novice with programming in general, so I didn't know running a program worked*. 

*Especially since most of my programs were really small before hand and didn't really have errors in them, so the program never acted this way before.

Answer (score 0):

The DOS window pops up because you are using the wrong python binary (python.exe instead of pythonw.exe?)

It does not show anything because, there is a bug in you program. If there is no stack trace I guess you forgot to enter the main loop. Try posting some code.

Comment: pythonw.exe would avoid the DOS window altogether.

Answer (score 0):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Line 3, in <module>
    import wx
ImportError: No module named wx
```

You need to install wxPython

Comment: It is installed, it's most likely just codepad.

Comment: It is not installed in the Python installation that you are using. The sentence fragment "it's most likely just codepad" makes no sense to me. I have no idea what you are trying to say.

Comment: codepad actually tries to run the pasted Python code, but codepad doesn't have wx installed. The error isn't what he's getting when he runs it.

Comment: There is no error being produced through the command prompt or through my editor. So I don't know whats going on.

Comment: I think you get an error. When I try to run the code I get this error:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "tetris.py", line 356, in <module>
            Tetris(None, -1, 'Tetris')
      File "tetris.py", line 10, in __init__
        self.statusbar - self.CreateStatusBar()
    AttributeError: 'Tetris' object has no attribute 'statusbar'

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change (at the bottom of your script)

```
app = wx.App()
```

to

```
app = wx.App(redirect=False)
```

Otherwise the segmentation faults that happen as wxPython is starting up won't be printed to the console, and can be a nightmare to track down.